# Settings.Bundle, Send email from preferences. (Bug reporter)

Tags: email, ios4, xcode4, preferences

Is it possible to send an email from my app's preferences (Settings.Bundle) for bug reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings.bundle does not have the ability of executing code like in an iOS app. The only thing you can do is implement a few controls and save those settings to `NSUserDefaults`.

See the docs here.
[Implementing Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Comment: i have seen this before, it is possible. But it might not be apple approved ? :/

Comment: well, you could have fields that the person fills out and then after the app launches you can check those fields and transmit the information if they are not null.